# Javascript, return the NOW hour and minutes padded by 5 minutes

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, math, time

I have a simple array of hours and minutes:

```
var hours = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
var minutes = ['00', '05', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50', '55'];
```

As you can see minutes are padded +5 minutes

Now i want to get the future nearest hour and minutes from the now Datetime

> So for example if now datetime is '09:07' i would like to return from
>   the arrays '09:10' or if now datetime is '10:21' to return '10:25',
>   because is the future nearest date available in the arrays.

And definitely i would like to know to which arrays index they (hour, minutes) both correspond to.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: something like `Math.ceil(currentMins / 5)` ?

Comment: @Hacketo looks cool.... need to try it, i would love answers so then i can accept them !

Comment: Seems not working, if it's 23 it returns 5, i need to return 25 in this case

Comment: i don't un derstand what you mean, index of what? :D

Comment: They mean `minutes[Math.ceil(currentMins / 5)]`

Comment: cool sorry didn't got you, it works perfectly! If you can please post as an answer ,)

Comment: @sbaaaang I think what you choose as answer does not work for edge cases, when time is 12:00  also check  when time is (12:59)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do simple math to get how many "5 mins" you got with [`date.getMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes), then get the closest highest integer.

```
 var date = new Date;

 var indexMinutes = Math.ceil(date.getMinutes() / 5);
 var indexHours = 0;

 if (indexMinutes == 12){
     indexMinutes = 0;
     indexHours = 1
 }

 indexHours = indexHours + (date.getHours() % 12 - 1);

 if (indexHours < 0 ) indexHours = 11;

 var paddedHour = hours[indexHours] + ":"+ minutes[indexMinutes];
```

Comment: You will need to put a check for the final index `00`, as 56 for example will give you index 12 (error).

Comment: I think it won't work correctly for `12:59`cases  @Hacketo

Comment: @Hacketo I think now it will break for `12:00`

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to get the current minutes value, then you should be able to use this on your minutes array.

```
var minutes = ['00', '05', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50', '55', '00'];
var minuteIndex = Math.ceil(curMinutes / 5);
console.log(minutes[minuteIndex]);
```

Notice that I have added an extra `'00'` to the end of the array. This is so that you don't need a boundary condition for any value greater than `55`. This should also work with exact minute values (like 12:00).

If you want the hours to work, then you simply have to cater to the instance where the minutes are `> 55` (as otherwise the hours are just their current value).

```
var hours = ['12', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
var hourIndex = (curHours % 12) + (minuteIndex === 12);
console.log(hours[hourIndex]);
```

Just note that I also added an extra `12` at the beginning to simplify the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with some adjustments for the indices.

```js
var hours = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'],
    minutes = ['00', '05', '10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50', '55'],
    date = new Date(),
    indexHour = date.getHours(),
    indexMinute = Math.ceil(date.getMinutes() / 5);

if (indexMinute >= 12) {
    indexHour++;
    indexMinute %= 12;
}
indexHour = (indexHour + 11) % 12;
document.write(hours[indexHour] + ':' + minutes[indexMinute]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oDate = new Date();
if (oDate.getMinutes() % 5 != 0) {
  oDate.setMinutes(((oDate.getMinutes()) / 5 + 1) * 5);
}
return oDate;
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do without array

```js
function pad(num) {
  return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num;
}


function formateTime(hours, minutes) {
  var roundMin = Math.ceil(minutes / 5) * 5;
  var roundHour = hours;

  if (roundMin === 60) {
    roundMin = 0;
    roundHour = (hours + 1) % 12;
  }

  return pad(roundHour) + ":" + pad(roundMin);
}


console.log(formateTime(12, 59)); // formateTime(date.getHour(), date.getMinutes());
console.log(formateTime(11, 31));
var date = new Date();
console.log(formateTime(date.getHours() % 12, date.getMinutes()));
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: OP ask about array indexes

Comment: maybe he hasn't seen other approach, the answer is here to so that he can choose from multiple answers/approaches